# I want to replace excell cell value using python

Tags: python, excel

Below is my excel file data and i want to replace b column values with some other values but without using cell refence like B2 instead of that i want to get cell index dynamically based on the values present in column then replace it

```
  A              B
```

1  Cust             dbcustcount

2  Card             dbCardcount

3  Account       dbAccountcount

Answer (score 0):

Load excel into pandas and apply pandas operations. Your example is very vague, hence I cannot give you any code solution at the moment

Comment: I have dbcustcount as values of cell and i want to replace it with actual cust count for ex 100 means i want to search dbcustcount in excel using python and replace it with 100 how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Load `.csv` file into pandas and apply some oprations you would to like.

[click here..](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-read-csv-using-pandas-read_csv/)